# mvc5 N tier architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am developing an mvc app with the following N tier structure:

DataAccess
Repository
Models
BusinessLogic

In my BusinessLogic folder I have an interface `IClinicBusiness` and a class `ClinicBusiness` that interfaces with IClinicBusiness.

The ClinicBusiness class is as follows:

```
    public void AddClinic(Clinic c)
    {

            var cr = new ClinicRepository();
            var clinc = new Clinic();

            if (c != null)
            {
                clinc.ClinicName = c.ClinicName;
                clinc.ClinicLocation = c.ClinicLocation;
            }
            cr.InsertClinic(c);
            cr.Save();
    }
}
```

The `ClinicBusiness` class implements a method from the Repository class library  eg. `InsertClinic();`

```
    public ClinicRepository()
    { }

    public ClinicRepository(DataContext clinics)
    {
        this.clinic = clinics;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Clinic> GetClinics()
    {
        return clinic.Clinics.ToList();
    }

    public Clinic GetClinicByID(int ClinicId)
    {
        return clinic.Clinics.Find(ClinicId);
    }

    public void InsertClinic(Clinic c)
    {
        clinic.Clinics.Add(c);
    }
```

In my controller I have an action

```
public ActionResult CreateClinic(Clinic c)
{
   var clinicBusiness = new ClinicRepository();


  return View(clinicBusiness.InsertClinic(c));
}
```

I get the following error cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, I think you want to change your repository `InsertClinic` method to

```
public Clinic InsertClinic(Clinic c)
{
    clinic.Clinics.Add(c);

    return c;
}
```

Or change your Action to

```
public ActionResult CreateClinic(Clinic c)
{
   var clinicBusiness = new ClinicRepository();
   clinicBusiness.InsertClinic(c)
   return View(c);
}
```

Again, it just depends on what your trying to accomplish and your view model.